# How to create a join that uses a subquery?

Tags: cakephp, join, subquery, query-builder, cakephp-2.x

How do you convert the following SQL Query to a CakePhp Find Query?

```sql
SELECT
    a.id, a.rev, a.contents
FROM
    YourTable a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        id, MAX(rev) rev
    FROM
        YourTable
    GROUP BY
        id
) b ON a.id = b.id AND a.rev = b.rev
```

I have tried the code below:

```
return $model->find('all', [
    'fields' => $fields,
    'joins' => [
        [
            'table' => $model->useTable,
            'fields' => ['id','MAX(rev) as rev'],
            'alias' => 'max_rev_table',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'group' => ['id'],
            'conditions' => [
                $model->name.'.id= max_rev_table.id',
                $model->name.'.rev = max_rev_table.rev'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'conditions' => [
        $model->name.'.emp_id' => $empId
    ]
]);
```

But it seems that in the generated SQL, the fields under the `joins` is not included. So I don't get the `max(rev)` which I need to get only the rows with `max(rev)`.

I have tried rearranging the items inside `joins` but still produces same auto-generated SQL.

Can you please help me?

Comment: which version of CakePHP are you using? Also, have you declared the relationships in your Model correctly?

Comment: I think I have the v2 CakePHP. I have also declared the relationships

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no `fields` or `group` options for joins, the only options are `table`, `alias`, `type`, and `conditions`.

If you want to join a subquery, then you need to explicitly generate one:

```
$ds = $model->getDataSource();
$subquery = $ds->buildStatement(
    array(
        'fields' => array('MaxRev.id', 'MAX(rev) as rev'),
        'table'  => $ds->fullTableName($model),
        'alias'  => 'MaxRev',
        'group'  => array('MaxRev.id')
    ),
    $model
);
```

and pass it to the joins `table` option:

```
'table' => "($subquery)"
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Models > Associations: Linking Models Together > Joining tables](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables)**
- **[Cookbook > Models > Retrieving Your Data > Sub-queries](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries)**

Comment: Is this better than using the 'query' function of the model?

Comment: @jaypax123 If you're referring to building a statement, then yes and no. `Model::query()` immediately executes a query, while `DboSource::buildStatement()` generates a query string, you can't compare the two in this situation.

Comment: I see. I tried your answer and it works fine. Thank you very much for your help! :)