# Cakephp 2.x : Is it possible to use SQL/find() results in cakephp joins instead of tables

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm currently developing something in Cakephp 2.7.5. I'm trying to convert some raw sql query to Cakephp style query (using `$model->find()`)

I'm stuck at a part where you have to join the results of two sub-queries to the same table. The solution i found was to use joins in cakephp : [Joining](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables)

But I need to join results of two subqueries and not of two tables. Can this be done in Cakephp?

Query I need:

```sql
SELECT
    `WorkflowExitDocument`.`app_no`,
    `WorkflowExitDocument`.`seq_no`,
    `WorkflowExitDocument`.`next_step`
FROM
    `ssc`.`workflow_exit_docs` AS `WorkflowExitDocument`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        APP_NO,
        MAX(SEQ_NO) AS SEQ_NO
    FROM
        workflow_exit_docs
    GROUP BY
        APP_NO
) AS PREVUSER
ON (
    `WorkflowExitDocument`.`app_no` = `PREVUSER`.`APP_NO` AND
    `WorkflowExitDocument`.`seq_no` = `PREVUSER`.`seq_no`
)
```

What I have so far:

```
$testJoin = $model->find('all', [
    'fields' => [
        $modelName.'.app_no,
        MAX('. $modelName.'.seq_no) AS seq_no'
    ],
    'group' => [
        $modelName.'.app_no'
    ],
    'recursive' => -1
]);

$options['fields'] = ['app_no', 'seq_no', 'next_step'];
$options['recursive'] = -1;
$options['joins'] = [
    [
        'table' => ($testJoin),
        'alias' => 'PREVUSER',
        'type' => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => [
            'WorkflowExitDocument.app_no = PREVUSER.APP_NO',
            'WorkflowExitDocument.seq_no = MAX(PREVUSER.seq_no)'
        ]
    ]
];

$test = $model->find('all', $options);
```

Comment: Check **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168867/how-to-create-a-join-that-uses-a-subquery**.